# How to ensure a webpage's content extends to the bottom of a webpage using only CSS

Tags: html, css

I have seen very similar questions on Stackoverflow regarding this issue but I have yet to find a solution that works for my scenario. As stated in the title I am looking for an only CSS solution and would prefer to avoid Javascript.

My issue is that I cannot figure out how to create a content box on a webpage that extends from the header of the page to the bottom of the page. The reason I am looking to extend this content box is to have a picture fill the background of the content box on the landing page of my website. I have tried two different techniques and neither one has worked correctly. I have attached both tests with fiddles  below:

Scenario One - Have a wrapper that extends the pages with the header and content within the wrapper.

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <header>

  </header>
  <div id="content">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body { 
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    min-width:1124px;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border: 3px solid black;
}
wrapper {
    min-height:100%;
    border: 3px solid blue;
    position:relative;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

header {
    height: 155px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;

    /*Top Gradient Defined*/
    background: #ffc578; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ffc578 0%, #fb9d23 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffc578), color-stop(100%,#fb9d23)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #ffc578 0%,#fb9d23 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #ffc578 0%,#fb9d23 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #ffc578 0%,#fb9d23 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #ffc578 0%,#fb9d23 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffc578', endColorstr='#fb9d23',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}

#content {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 1100px;
    position: relative;
    margin-right:auto; 
    margin-left:auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    height:100%;
    padding:0;
    border: 5px solid red;
    background-color:black;
    background-size:cover;
    position: relative;
}
```

Fiddle for Scenario 1: http://jsfiddle.net/tPNB4/5/

As you can see the content div will only expand to the length of the content and no the entire length of the wrapper div.

Scenario Two: Have the content sit below the header div.

HTML:

```
<header>

</header>
<div id="content">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body { 
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    min-width:1124px;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border: 3px solid black;
}


header {
    height: 155px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;

    /*Top Gradient Defined*/
    background: #ffc578; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ffc578 0%, #fb9d23 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffc578), color-stop(100%,#fb9d23)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #ffc578 0%,#fb9d23 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #ffc578 0%,#fb9d23 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #ffc578 0%,#fb9d23 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #ffc578 0%,#fb9d23 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffc578', endColorstr='#fb9d23',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}

#content {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 1100px;
    position: relative;
    margin-right:auto; 
    margin-left:auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    height:100%;
    padding:0;
    border: 5px solid red;
    background-color:black;
    background-size:cover;
    position: relative;
}
```

Fiddle for scenario 2 - http://jsfiddle.net/6MGrh/2/

As you can see the content box extends past the length of the page and generates the scroll bar.

If anyone could provide some guidance on why neither of these scenarios is working that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's not possible. You'll have to end up either using the box model or compromising something somewhere or using javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to use absolute positioning of your elements. The content section is then offset by the height of the header and optional footer.

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/GVPqP/1

```
div{min-height:50px;width:90%;
  border:1px solid #aaa;
  position:absolute;left:0;right:0;
}

#header{top:0;}
#content{top:50px;bottom:50px;}
#footer{bottom:0;}
```

Comment: Thanks Luke, this does solve the problem, but similar to the answer above it hinders the layout of the webpage. On re-sizing the page the content within the absolute areas of the page will not remain properly located. I was hoping for a solution that used CSS with relative positioning, rather then absolute.

Comment: what do you mean by not properly located? This update uses a bg image for the content - http://jsfiddle.net/GVPqP/3/

Comment: Your example works correctly with the image, the issue is that I have text on top of the image on the landing page.  As the landing page is defined as an absolute element, upon re-sizing the window the text will not position itself correctly relative to the image.

Comment: I cant seem to replicate the issue. This example has text as well. But it doesn't move when re-sizing the window - http://jsfiddle.net/GVPqP/4/

Answer (score 0):

Notice you specify header height in pixels and everything else in %'s also note
the excess is exactly 155px over the page.
The header was pushing everything downwards because you told `content` to take room already taken by the header

#### new css:

```
html, body, div, header {
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
html, body {
    ....
    height:100%;
    ....
}
#wrapper {
    height:100%;
    ....
}
header {
    height: 20%;
    width: 100%;
    ....
    /*Top Gradient Defined*/
    .....
}
#content {
    .....
    height:80%;
    ....
}
```

**[Here's a jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/tPNB4/9/)**

Comment: This still results in the same problem that occurred in scenario 2 as the content now extends beyond the webpage resulting in a scroll bar, see the box with the red border. What I am looking to do is have it only extend to the bottom of the webpage resulting in no scroll bar.

Comment: I also tried that out as well, the issue is that I have images that appear in the header (logo, nav, graphics etc..) that are a set height. Thus when you change the height of the header the images and navigation panels do not scale with the changing size of the browser. so I am looking for a way to keep my header a fixed size and still have the content div stretch to the bottom of the screen.